# Can 2 players play on different controllers?

Tags: fifa-13

Is it possible for two players, using separate controllers, to play at the same time?

Comment: Are you basically asking if it has a local multiplayer option, via split or shared screen, or what have you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main menu go:

1. EAS FC Matchday
2. Kick off
3. Select sides using two controllers.
4. Pick your teams etc.

You should be able to figure it out from there. [Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/664911-fifa-soccer-13/65219127)